# CSS: 3-column <ul> layout with paired <li>-elements

Tags: html, css

Looking for a way to style the list, that it looks like a grid.

```
<div class="name">
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  ...
<ul>
```

In my css i already used:

```
.name {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 20px;
}
```

Right now every `<li>` element is lying under the one before.

```
1            3
Text         Text
2            4
Text         ....
```

I want to achieve following: Every 2nd `<li>` will be paired with the one before:

```
1 Text                   4 Text                   7 Text
2 Text                   5 Text                   8 Text
3 Text                   6 Text                   9 Text
```

How do achieve that? PS: If possible w/o adding classes to the `<ul>` or `<li>` elements.

Comment: Could you put a <span> after each number and reduce the li's by 1/2?

Comment: Could you post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) please?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a table?

Comment: @TimSPQR No, thats not possible.

Comment: @apaul34208 The list is created by a framework called Wicket. Can't influence it. Same reason i can't add any elements into the list, it's created by the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with pseudo classes, but it's really hacky, and won't work below IE9 (which I guess you may not care about since you tried to use css columns). You'd be much better off either modding the original code, or trying to alter the dom with some js.

**Code:**

```
.name {
    width: 600px; // set to whatevs. Should work with or without width.
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 1%;
    box-sizing: border-box; // need to set this if you want to pad the list items
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
    color: #f0f;
    width: 1%;
}

li:nth-child(even){
    color: #00F;
    width: 31.3333%; // using this number as a root since you want three cols 
                     // (33.333%, minus the 2% for width and padding above).
                     // No matter what you want, make sure total width == 100%
}

li:nth-child(7n){
    clear:both;      // clear the 7th (or new row) element
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/6uSzS/

Answer (score 1):

i changed your code:
see it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/zq9VR/)

i used `:nth-of-type` selector for that! but i recommend you to use `table` tag
**CSS:**

```
*{
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.name{
    position:relative;
    width:90%;
    margin:0;
    margin-left:5%;
    background:#e7e7e7;
    padding:0;
}
div.name li{
    color:#2E99DB;
    width:2%;
    display:inline-block;
}
div.name li:nth-of-type(even){
    color:#000;
    width:21%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="name">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>Text</li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

**notice:** use more accurate scales for width ...